# How to transform (rotate) svg text element without changing coordinates?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, bar-chart

I'm new to this d3.js. Here I'm trying to draw a bar chart using the d3.v3.js library. Here I'm facing few problems. I have tried to include measure labels onto the y-axis. But once I transform the labels -90 degree its position is automatically changing.

Here's the code I'm used to drawing:

```
    svg.append("g")
    .attr("id","x_axis")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")  
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", ".15em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");
    // .attr("transform", "translate(" + bandSize + ", 0)")

    svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("id","dimLabel")
    .append("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("x", width/2)
    .attr("y", height+55) 
    .text(dimensionLabels[0]);




    svg.append("g")
    .attr("id","y_axis1")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "label")
    //.attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", function(d){return y(d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Metric1; }));});


    //Measure Labels
    svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("id","measureLabels")
    .append("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", height/2) 
    .text(measureLabels[0]+", "+measureLabels[1])
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");
```

Output Image:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: would be usefull if you provide more code or even fiddle like thid https://jsfiddle.net/vintharas/0m9raoj4/

Comment: Have you tried to use `text-anchor: middle` instead of end (In Measure Labels part)?

Comment: Thank You guys for the reply.
Sorry this the very first time I'm posting a query on Stackoverflow. I'll Include a jsfiddle. @ shareef
 I have tried text-anchor:middle it gives me the same result. But this time position is changed a little @rm4.

Comment: Where do you expect the label to be? Maybe you can also try start instead of end

Comment: I expect the label to be on the left side of the y-axis. I tried all strat, end, middle.
.attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
This line changes the position from left to right.
Could you please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Please refer to the output image

Comment: `rotate(<angle>)` rotates about the origin of the local coordinate system. `rotate(<angle> <x>, <y>)` rotates about the coordinates you give.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you see right now is the expected result, because the `rotate` function of the `transform` attribute rotates the element around the origin (0,0), not around its center.

The easiest solution is dropping your `attr("x")` and `attr("y")` and positioning the text using the same `transform`:

```js
var width = 300,
  height = 300;
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);
var text = svg.append("text")
  .text("Sum (sales), Sum (quantity)")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("transform", "translate(20," + (height / 2) + ") rotate(-90)")
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Another solution is setting the center of the `rotate` to the same `x` and `y` values:

```js
var width = 300,
  height = 300;
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);
var text = svg.append("text")
  .text("Sum (sales), Sum (quantity)")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("x", 20)
  .attr("y", 150)
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90, 20, 150)")
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the second solution: setting the center of the `rotate` is a very good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the css property `transform-origin`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin